# add data from a web part text area, in single item of the list (JS)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am new in JS,JQ. Please help me out. i am using this code to save data in the list by click on save button. and save data in local storage on focusOut. now i need some changes, i will not use save button i just need to save data with focusOut in list, not in local storage. as well as i need to store data in single item of the list. dont want to have bundle of items in the list after every focus out. so overwrite previous item with new item. and dont want to lose data in text box web part when page Reload or close. here is the code.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/sticky_note.css">
<h2> Sticky Notes </h2>
<br />




<textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="StickyText" >

</textarea>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Save"  />
<ul id="list">

</ul>

 <script src='https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/Style Library/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
<script src='https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/sticky_note.js'></script>
```

JS:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    var new_task = $('#StickyText').val();
    $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
    AddData()
});
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");

}
function AddData() {
    var listName = "StickyNotes";
    var newItemTitle = $("#StickyText").val();
    var url = "https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/teamsite";
    addListItem(url, listName , newItemTitle)
}

// CREATE Operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// weburl: The url of the web that the list is in. 
// newItemTitle: New Item title.
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails


function addListItem(url, listname, metadataName) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listname);
    var taskProperties = {
        '__metadata': { 'type': itemType },
        'Title': metadataName
    };

    createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, listname, taskProperties)
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log('Task has been created successfully');
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties) {
    return getFormDigest(webUrl).then(function (data) {

        return $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }
        });
    });
}

function getFormDigest(webUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}


//keep saving data in local storage
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("stickies") != null){
     $("#StickyText").val(localStorage.getItem("stickies"));
    }

    $("#StickyText").focusout(function(){
    var sticky = $("#StickyText").val();
     localStorage.setItem("stickies", sticky);   
    });
 });
```